# Parse XML value with Name Space in SQl

Tags: sql, xml

I have following XML :

```
<ProductionSchedule xmlns:inp2="http://www.wbf.org/xml/B2MML-V0401" xmlns="http://www.wbf.org/xml/B2MML-V0401">
  <inp2:ProductionRequest>
    <inp2:ID>0916A</inp2:ID>
    <inp2:Description>SUBH190916A</inp2:Description>
    <inp2:Location>
      <inp2:EquipmentID>MYEqupiment</inp2:EquipmentID>
    </inp2:Location>
    <inp2:SegmentRequirement>
      <inp2:ID>000</inp2:ID>
      <inp2:EarliestStartTime>2015-10-17T12:00:00</inp2:EarliestStartTime>
      <inp2:LatestEndTime>2015-10-19T12:00:00</inp2:LatestEndTime>
      <inp2:MaterialProducedRequirement>
        <inp2:MaterialDefinitionID>GEEC3MA0025EMZI</inp2:MaterialDefinitionID>
        <inp2:Quantity>
          <inp2:QuantityString>2</inp2:QuantityString>
        </inp2:Quantity>
        <inp2:MaterialProducedRequirementProperty>
          <inp2:ID>ERPWOStatus</inp2:ID>
          <inp2:Value>
            <inp2:ValueString>Released</inp2:ValueString>
          </inp2:Value>
        </inp2:MaterialProducedRequirementProperty>
        <inp2:MaterialProducedRequirementProperty>
          <inp2:ID>ROUTING</inp2:ID>
          <inp2:Value>
            <inp2:ValueString>SOmeMPRVaue</inp2:ValueString>
          </inp2:Value>
        </inp2:MaterialProducedRequirementProperty>
        <inp2:MaterialProducedRequirementProperty>
          <inp2:ID>MPValue2</inp2:ID>
          <inp2:Value>
            <inp2:ValueString>2016-01-21T12:00:00</inp2:ValueString>
          </inp2:Value>
        </inp2:MaterialProducedRequirementProperty>
      </inp2:MaterialProducedRequirement>
    </inp2:SegmentRequirement>
  </inp2:ProductionRequest>
</ProductionSchedule>
```

I am trying to get the value MPValue2 , from the XML.

I tried with following:

```
Select `@xml.value('(/ProductionSchedule/inp2:ProductionRequest/inp2:SegmentRequirement/inp2:MaterialProducedRequirement/inp2:MaterialProducedRequirementProperty)[1]','nvarchar(255)')`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select is OK, but you must consider/declare the namespaces:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.wbf.org/xml/B2MML-V0401'
                  ,'http://www.wbf.org/xml/B2MML-V0401' AS inp2)
Select @xml.value('(/ProductionSchedule/inp2:ProductionRequest/inp2:SegmentRequirement/inp2:MaterialProducedRequirement/inp2:MaterialProducedRequirementProperty)[1]','nvarchar(255)')
```

This works too (wildcard) but it's better to be as specific as possible:

```
Select @xml.value('(/*:ProductionSchedule/*:ProductionRequest/*:SegmentRequirement/*:MaterialProducedRequirement/*:MaterialProducedRequirementProperty)[1]','nvarchar(255)')
```

The *fast and lazy* would work too :-) but **not fast in terms of performance...**

```
Select @xml.value('(//*:MaterialProducedRequirementProperty)[1]','nvarchar(255)')
```

### UPDATE

This is the query to get all your Properties:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.wbf.org/xml/B2MML-V0401'
                  ,'http://www.wbf.org/xml/B2MML-V0401' AS inp2)
SELECT prop.value('(inp2:ID)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Property
FROM @xml.nodes('/ProductionSchedule/inp2:ProductionRequest/inp2:SegmentRequirement/inp2:MaterialProducedRequirement/inp2:MaterialProducedRequirementProperty') AS A(prop)
```

The result

```
Property
--------
ERPWOStatus
ROUTING
MPValue2
```

### UPDATE 2: Use the ID as filter in `XQuery`

See how I added the filter at the end of the `XPath` in `.nodes()`.

Nodes will return all sub-elements *row-wise*. The filter will reduce the resultset to one single row (if `inp2:ID` is unique!) and then read the `Value/ValueString`.

I let the namespace declaration for `DEFAULT` and `inp2`. But, as @Serf pointed out correctly, both URLs are equal. It would be enough to declare only the `DEFAULT` and query without any namespace-prefixes...

```
DECLARE @TheID NVARCHAR(100)='MPValue2';
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.wbf.org/xml/B2MML-V0401'
                  ,'http://www.wbf.org/xml/B2MML-V0401' AS inp2)
SELECT prop.value('(inp2:Value/inp2:ValueString)[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS Property
FROM @xml.nodes('/ProductionSchedule/inp2:ProductionRequest/inp2:SegmentRequirement/inp2:MaterialProducedRequirement/inp2:MaterialProducedRequirementProperty[inp2:ID=sql:variable("@TheID")]') AS A(prop)
```

Comment: But I need to get the value for 'SOmeMPRVaue' which is on third MaterialProducedRequirementProperty. And I do not want to go by Index , but whose node value is SOmeMPRVaue , get the ValueString

Comment: @Simsons This should work with the path `prop.value('(inp2:Value/inp2:ValueString)[1]','nvarchar(100)`

Comment: Can we use where clause instead of index?

Comment: @Simsons, you might read the data as derived table and use a `WHERE`, or you can add a filter condition (`XQuery`) into the `XPath`. What do you want to filter? What is the unique name/id/mark to know which node to read?

Comment: By chance both namespaces are the equal, so DEFAULT declaration   and unprefixed names '/ProductionSchedule/ProductionRequest...' should be quite enough,

Comment: @Serg, you are right :-) just copy'n'pasted the URLs and did not read them carefully...

Comment: @Shungo, The ID is BOMExplosionDate and need to access ValueString ,

Comment: @Simsons please see Update 2

Comment: @Shungo, Yes , That's what is the requirement